# How can i add ngnix service to Cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I would like to use ngnix instead of Apache for the FrontEnd of PHP Applications in my cloudfoundry instalation, is that possible?

So the idea is to use PHP-FPM instead of mod_php

any example/receipt would be much appreciated,

thanks

Comment: Which particular component are you talking about? Apache isn't used in Cloud Foundry, all HTTP proxying is done using NginX

Comment: sorry i meant as the frontend of the application, to replace mod_php and make much speedier php applications, just updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more recent versions of Cloud Foundry, installed via BOSH and not dev_setup include support for build packs. I see no reason why you couldn't include nginx and php-fpm in a build pack for php. We're working on documentation for building all the "bleeding edge" stuff on virtual environments like OpenStack, AWS and VSphere, but this will all be via our tool "BOSH".

There is a build of Micro Cloud Foundry that supports build packs, however, at this moment that particular build does not support running services, I can provide the link if needed.

Comment: That sounds great, its that stable enough to put it in a production environment?

Comment: Micro Cloud Foundry is only intended for development use. If you're looking at building a production instance. The only way we really advise build a production instance is via our tool BOSH. This requires a VM based infrastructure such as AWS, OpenStack or VMWare vSphere. Documentation exists here -> http://cloudfoundry.github.com/docs/running/deploying-cf/ this is being updated all the time and a draught version for AWS should materialise soon too!